# Running a program consist of try block but without catch or final clauses

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Usually this would give syntax error. But in the [oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) in `try-with-resources` Statement section , there are several code samples with `try` block but without `catch` or `finally` statements. How come this codes does not give syntax errors?

Comment: Because it was added to the language spec like that in Java 7.

Comment: Why do you believe they should cause a syntax error? A new syntax has new rules, is that so surprising?

Comment: The likelihood is, the method has been declared to throw the resulting exception, try-with-resources is (effectively) the same as try-finally

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559661/java-try-catch-finally-blocks-without-catch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **try with resources** block, an implicit `finally` is added with code calling the `close()` method on all `Closable` instances...

So, a `finally` is still present in the block. So it's syntactically correct.

Comment: @Optimuskck new as in Java 7 is so old, it isn't publicly supported ;)

Answer (score 1):

The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.

The following example reads the first line from a file. It uses an instance of BufferedReader to read data from the file. BufferedReader is a resource that must be closed after the program is finished with it:

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
try (BufferedReader br =
               new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    return br.readLine();
}
}
```

In this example, the resource declared in the try-with-resources statement is a BufferedReader. The declaration statement appears within parentheses immediately after the try keyword. The class BufferedReader, in Java SE 7 and later, implements the interface java.lang.AutoCloseable. Because the BufferedReader instance is declared in a try-with-resource statement, it will be closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly (as a result of the method BufferedReader.readLine throwing an IOException).

Read more here : 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Quote from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.2:

> 14.20.3.2 Extended try-with-resources
>
> A try-with-resources statement with at least one catch clause and/or a
>   finally clause is called an extended try-with-resources statement. The
>   meaning of an extended try-with-resources statement:
>
> ```
> try ResourceSpecification
>     Block
> Catches//opt
> Finally//opt
> ```
>
> is given by the following translation to a basic try-with-resources
>   statement (§14.20.3.1) nested inside a try-catch or try-finally or
>   try-catch-finally statement:
>
> ```
> try {
>     try ResourceSpecification
>         Block
> }
> Catches//opt
> Finally//opt
> ```
>
> The effect of the translation is to put the ResourceSpecification
>   "inside" the try statement. This allows a catch clause of an extended
>   try-with-resources statement to catch an exception due to the
>   automatic initialization or closing of any resource. So, basically,
>   wrapper is already implemented