# good practice with try-finally in java?

Tags: java, try-catch-finally, try-finally

I ran into a little problem today where I have a piece of code like this, which made me a little uncomfortable...

```
   try{
       //stuff...
   } finally {
       //finally stuff
   }
```

I wonder if such implementation is a good practice in terms of when an exception occurs in the `try` and is re-thrown to the caller who handles it. Is this equivalent to the code below?

```
    try{
        //code....
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handling...
    } finally {
        //finishing up
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Difference between try-finally and try-catch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854910/difference-between-try-finally-and-try-catch)

Comment: I looked at that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854910/difference-between-try-finally-and-try-catch but I still kind of confused... maybe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not equivalent, because of the reason you already gave: The exception is still thrown in the first case. And there might be reasons, where you exactly want such a behavior: Close resources, e.g. Streams in `finally` block, but throw the exception out of the enclosing method, to handle it else where.

Btw., you can also "abuse" `try`-`finally` constructs, in case no exception is expected at all:

```
private StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

private String getBuffer() {
    try {
            // return current String content of the buffer
            return buffer.toString();
    } finally {
            // assign a new StringBuilder, before method returns
            buffer = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, in my case it is an 'abuse' as you described it. Nice example by the way...

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly, a `try/finally` block without `catch` is the equivalent of

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw;
} finally {
    // finishing up
}
```

Where you just re throw the exception without handling it. Omitting the `catch` block is good if this is what you intended to do, it improves the code readability.